# Ionic Nuxt 3 problem running app on physical device through Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, nuxt.js

I've been trying to install and test an app on my iPhone but it is not working. After I installed @nuxtjs/ionic to my project and trying to run the app on my device through Xcode I get these errors

```
⚡️  WebView loaded
⚡️  [error] - [nuxt] error caught during app initialization {}
```

in the console and

```
Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase.
```

in the sidebar and the app has white screen forever. This only happens if I have @nuxtjs/ionic installed. So is the module problematic?

Also it successfully runs on an emulator or live server but not in physical device

Tried to change the node version

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar issue once I added `~/pages`

Error arises on *line 110* in `~/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/nuxt.js` while trying to get `{ provide }` during destructuring assignment.  Here is the **temporary workaround** by adding `try/catch`:

```
export async function applyPlugin(nuxtApp, plugin) {
  if (plugin.hooks) {
    nuxtApp.hooks.addHooks(plugin.hooks);
  }
  if (typeof plugin === "function") {
    try { // fix :: ⚡️  [error] - [nuxt] error caught during app initialization {} :: savva
      const { provide } = await nuxtApp.runWithContext(() => plugin(nuxtApp)) || {};
      if (provide && typeof provide === "object") {
        for (const key in provide) {
          nuxtApp.provide(key, provide[key]);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // end fix :: ⚡️
    }
  }
}
```

My configuration:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@capacitor/cli": "5.5.1",
  "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
  "@nuxtjs/ionic": "^0.12.1",
  "nuxt": "^3.8.0",
  "typescript": "^5.2.2",
  "vue": "^3.3.7",
  "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
},
```

Looking forward to a more permanent solution!